# What django-tastypie authentication is most suitable for multiclient (jquery/android/iOS) application?

Tags: jquery, django, authentication, tastypie

Im developing REST Api application with django-based backend and Im using tastypie packege for development of API resources. I want to create three clients (Android application, iOS app and website developed in jquery framework ember.js), each of them have to access my resources.

So far I have ember.js frontend which http requests are authenticated by SessionAuthentication using default django/admin settings.

I have no experience with auth processes, but I think it wont be possible to use this sessions in Android or iOS app.

So which one (or one is not enough?) of these classes provided by tastypie:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html

is most suitable for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I worked in similar scenario. Used MultiAuthentication with SessionAuthentication for web and ApiKeyAuthentication for IOS and android.